# Sending email through Appcelerator Cloud API

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I was trying to send email through Appcelerator Cloud Service, in my Titanium app. The code I'm using is the standart one, given at the documentation site. But the email is not being sent.

```
Cloud.Emails.send({
    template: 'welcome',
    recipients: '*******@gmail.com'
    },
    function (e) {
        if (e.success) {
        Titanium.API.info('Email sent successfully.');
    } else {
        Titanium.API.info('Error:\\n' +
            ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
    }
});
```

It give the this error, 'Email template welcome is not found'. I was thinking that template is the message to be sent in email. There is no help on API about this attribute , template. Can anybody explain it to me? I'll be thankful.

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error shows that you haven't created an email template on the ACS website yet. The following steps will help you to create email template

1. Log in to your Appcelerator App Console
2. click "Manage ACS" under the app you're working on
3. click the "Email Templates" tab
4. "Create an Email Template".

also you can setup your SMTP settings as follows which worked for me.

**Username: *_*__*_*____@gmail.com
Password: gmail account password
TLS: true/ false (both will work)
SMTP Address: smtp.gmail.com
Port: *587*
Domain : www.gmail.com**

Answer (score 0):

That error means you haven't created an email template on the ACS website yet. Log in to your [Appcelerator App Console](https://my.appcelerator.com/apps/titanium), click "Manage ACS" under the app you're working on, then click the "Email Templates" tab, and "Create an Email Template".

Comment: Now getting error about non-configured SMTP. Tried to do it but failed. Following are the configurations, I was using.
I'm unable to configure SMTP settings for my app. I'm using following configurations.
    Username: ____________@gmail.com    
    Password: gmail account password
    TLS: true
    SMTP Address: smtp.gmail.com
    Port: 465
When I click on save settings, a pop-up asks for email address. I'm using _________@gmail.com there. But settings are not configured. Please help me in this problem.

Comment: Sorry, you're on your own with your SMTP settings. You might check to make sure SMTP is enabled for your gmail account. I just tested that ACS is able to send email through my gmail account, so it is something you are doing wrong.