# error during smtp setting in ACS titanium

Tags: smtp, gmail, titanium

I'm trying to save my smtp setting as;

```
**username:_________@gmail.com
password:gmail accout paswrd
TSL: true
       smtp address: smtp.gmail.com
      Port: 587
        Domain:gmail.com
       Authentication:login
       set default sender: false
     test mode: false**
```

But it shows me following error;
""smtp check failed getaddrinfo:Name or service not known""

Comment: similar question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453794/sending-email-through-appcelerator-cloud-api

Comment: are sure SMTP is enabled for your gmail account?? double check it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [Sending Email Through Appcelerator Cloud API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453794/sending-email-through-appcelerator-cloud-api)

Try the following in your SMTP settings

```
Username: ________@gmail.com
Password: gmail account password
TLS: true/ false (both will work)
SMTP Address: smtp.gmail.com
Port: 587
Domain : www.gmail.com
```

Note that Domain should be `www.gmail.com`

Answer (score 0):

the best way to setup SMTP with gmail will be the following

1. GO to https://myaccount.google.com/u/2/security
2. Turn on

   a. Less secure app access.

   b. 2FA authentication.

Then generate an **app password** in signing in to google. the guide is here https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en. Make sure to use the same name of the app in there as you created the name for mobile backend data service app in ACS dashboard.

After that in the Appcelerator cloud dashboard, use the below info

```
Username: the email address
Password: the 16 digit app password you got from google.
Smtp address: smtp.gmail.com
Domain: gmail.com / www.gmail.com either works.
Port:587
Authentication: Plain
Default sender email: same as username / or any other
Test mode: Disabled
TLS: Enabled
```

Thanks.